# Versioning local python packages with conda

Tags: python, continuous-integration, anaconda, conda, release-management

Let's assume we have a project with depends heavy on Python scientific computing ecosystem (pandas, numpy, scikit learn, seaborn etc.). [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) or [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) is a natural choice because it offers good dependency management between these libraries, virtual enviroments (which are shareable across teams) and it is well-documented. I want to lock down a set of external libraries and their version that are used across the team.

Now further assume that the team produces its own internal proprietary python analytics libraries and applications. We cannot share these libraries and applications publicly. Furthermore, ideally we have a release system (versioning and dev branch etc.) and dependency management between the internal packages. Is it possible to host the packages on a private local conda channel? What about versioning and releasing? Can conda do this stand alone or are additional tools required? What works well in conjunction with conda for this purpose and doesn't add too much complexity.

Comment: See: https://conda.io/docs/custom-channels.html